# Catching multiple exception types in one catch block

Tags: php, exception

I'd like a cleaner way to obtain the following functionality, to catch `AError` and `BError` in one block:

```
try
{
    /* something */
}
catch( AError, BError $e )
{
    handler1( $e )
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    handler2( $e )
}
```

Is there any way to do this? Or do I have to catch them separately?

`AError` and `Berror` have a shared base class, but they also share it with other types that I'd like to fall through to `handler2`, so I can't just catch the base class.

Comment: Just to add this as a side note: An RFC has been filed for catching multiple exceptions. Let's see if this feature get's it's way into the PHP language ... https://wiki.php.net/rfc/multiple-catch

Comment: ^ This feature has been implemented in PHP 7.1

Comment: In PHP 8.0 there is even cleaner way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64159544/7082164

Answer (score 531, accepted):

#### Update:

As of PHP 7.1, this is available.

The syntax is:

```
try
{
    // Some code...
}
catch(AError | BError $e)
{
    // Handle exceptions
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // Handle the general case
}
```

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#example-334

RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/multiple-catch

Commit: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/0aed2cc2a440e7be17552cc669d71fdd24d1204a

---

#### For PHP before 7.1:

Despite what these other answers say, you can catch `AError` and `BError` in the same block (it is somewhat easier if you are the one defining the exceptions). Even given that there are exceptions you want to "fall through", you should still be able to define a hierarchy to match your needs.

```
abstract class MyExceptions extends Exception {}

abstract class LetterError extends MyExceptions {}

class AError extends LetterError {}

class BError extends LetterError {}
```

Then:

```
catch(LetterError $e){
    //voodoo
}
```

As you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/%7Ehelly/php/ext/spl/classException.html), even the `SPL` default exceptions have a hierarchy you can leverage. Additionally, as stated in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be
> executed, and **PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block.**

This means you could also have

```
class CError extends LetterError {}
```

which you need to handle differently than `AError` or `BError`, so your catch statement would look like this:

```
catch(CError $e){
    //voodoo
}
catch(LetterError $e){
    //voodoo
}
```

If you had the case where there were twenty or more exceptions that legitimately belonged under the same superclass, and you needed to handle five (or whatever large-ish group) of them one way and the rest the other, you can STILL do this.

```
interface Group1 {}

class AError extends LetterError implements Group1 {}

class BError extends LetterError implements Group1 {}
```

And then:

```
catch (Group1 $e) {}
```

Using OOP when it comes to exceptions is very powerful. Using things like `get_class` or `instanceof` are hacks, and should be avoided if possible.

Another solution I would like to add is putting the exception handling functionality in its own method.

You could have

```
function handleExceptionMethod1(Exception $e)
{
    //voodoo
}

function handleExceptionMethod2(Exception $e)
{
    //voodoo
}
```

Assuming there is absolutely no way you can control exception class hierarchies or interfaces (and there almost always *will* be a way), you can do the following:

```
try
{
    stuff()
}
catch(ExceptionA $e)
{
    $this->handleExceptionMethod1($e);
}
catch(ExceptionB $e)
{
    $this->handleExceptionMethod1($e);
}
catch(ExceptionC $e)
{
    $this->handleExceptionMethod1($e);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $this->handleExceptionMethod2($e);
}
```

In this way, you are still have a only single code location you have to modify if your exception handling mechanism needs to change, and you are working within the general constructs of OOP.

Comment: Here's another vote for this as the correct answer. Unfortunately stuff like what is said in the accepted answer and the fact that it is accepted as the correct answer, is what makes PHP the madness that it is.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Although, it assumes that you are able to modify the files. `AError` could be implemented in a library/file which is updated by a third party.

Comment: @WaffleStealer654 You can still subclass the files and make those implement your group, even if you can't edit the files directly. That would presume you can throw the exceptions, but you could just wrap the most base-level mechanism where the exception would be throw and then catch it and throw your wrapped exception.

Comment: This is not the accepted answer, because you cannot do that when you use a 3rd party library.

Comment: @DenisV See my comment above yours. It is done all the time in enterprise software. Encapsulation is great.

Comment: @MirroredFate tell this to Zend Framework developers ;)

Comment: I learnt a lot about leveraging OOP exceptions from this answer.

Answer (score 238):

In PHP >= 7.1 this is possible. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325523/31671).

---

If you can modify the exceptions, [use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325523/31671).

If you can't, you could try catching all with `Exception` and then check which exception was thrown with [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php).

```
try
{
    /* something */
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    if ($e instanceof AError OR $e instanceof BError) {
       // It's either an A or B exception.
    } else {
        // Keep throwing it.
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

**But** it would probably be better to [use multiple catch blocks as described in aforementioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325523/31671).

```
try
{
    /* something */
}
catch( AError $e )
{
   handler1( $e );
}
catch ( BError $b )
{
   handler2( $e );
}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Catching them together and testing the type would be good if there were many error types that needed to be handled together, but for only 2, such as in my case, catching them separately is probably cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: @DominicGurto: Yeah, I'd go with that too :) I'd be more concerned with PHP's attitude towards a `finally` statement. ;)

Comment: But don't forget that this catches ALL exceptions, so there should be something like `... } else { throw($e); }` if it doesn't match the two. Sorry for maybe wrong syntax, didn't see php a while.

Comment: *"Is there any way to do this? Or do I have to catch them separately?"* -- The answer says no. In fact there is.

Comment: @rdlowrey: No, I said it's not possible with the code example the OP used. Then I suggested a workaround.

Comment: I suppose we can keep it civil and agree to disagree, then :)

Comment: @rdlowrey: I think you're better off saying "the suggestion in this answer works, I have another suggestion that may suit your requirements better". It's a bit overboard to call it incorrect.

Comment: In that case, my apologies. Perhaps I got a little too worked up. I've amended my answer and am about to delete my comment.

Comment: If you read the first paragraph here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php you will see multiple catch blocks are possible and perfectly valid solution. The OP though had mistakenly put two exception classes in one catch statement. I think it will be better to update your answer with another example with multiple catch blocks.

Comment: Suggesting a solution that eats all your other Exceptions, shouldn't have been accepted at all...

Comment: I realise this answer wasn't so great, so I updated it to the better advice, with links to the original poster.

Comment: Note that as of PHP 7.1 you _can_ specify multiple exception classes in a single statement by separating them with `|`. See the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325523/

Answer (score 90):

Coming in [PHP 7.1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/multiple-catch) is the ability to catch multiple types.

So that this:

```
<?php
try {
    /* ... */
} catch (FirstException $ex) {
    $this->manageException($ex);
} catch (SecondException $ex) {
    $this->manageException($ex);
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
try {

} catch (FirstException | SecondException $ex) {
    $this->manageException($ex);
}
?>
```

are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 57):

As of PHP 7.1,

```
catch( AError | BError $e )
{
    handler1( $e )
}
```

interestingly, you can also:

```
catch( AError | BError $e )
{
    handler1( $e )
} catch (CError $e){
    handler2($e);
} catch(Exception $e){
    handler3($e);
}
```

and in earlier versions of PHP:

```
catch(Exception $ex){
    if($ex instanceof AError || $ex instanceof BError){
        //handle AError and BError
    } elseif($ex instanceof CError){
        //handle CError
    } else {
       throw $ex; // an unknown exception occurred, throw it further
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

This article covers the question [electrictoolbox.com/php-catch-multiple-exception-types](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-catch-multiple-exception-types/). Content of the post copied directly from the article:

**Example exceptions**

Here's some example exceptions that have been defined for the purposes of this example:

```
class FooException extends Exception 
{
  public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0) 
  {
    // do something
  }
}

class BarException extends Exception 
{
  public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0) 
  {
    // do something
  }
}

class BazException extends Exception 
{
  public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0) 
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

**Handling multiple exceptions**

It's very simple - there can be a catch block for each exception type that can be thrown:

```
try 
{
  // some code that might trigger a Foo/Bar/Baz/Exception
}

catch(FooException $e) 
{
  // we caught a foo exception
}

catch(BarException $e) 
{
  // we caught a bar exception
}

catch(BazException $e) 
{
  // we caught a baz exception
}

catch(Exception $e) 
{
  // we caught a normal exception
  // or an exception that wasn't handled by any of the above
}
```

If an exception is thrown that is not handled by any of the other catch statements it will be handled by the catch(Exception $e) block. It does not necessarily have to be the last one.

Comment: The problem with this method comes when you have to execute the same code for two or more different Exceptions.

Comment: This was retrieved from [Electric Toolbox](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-catch-multiple-exception-types/). Editing post to give credit.

Comment: With PHP 7.x, you need to `catch (Throwable $e)` to catch all exceptions. See also: http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php

Answer (score 23):

As an extension to the accepted answer, you could switch the type of Exception resulting in a pattern that is somewhat like the original example:

```
try {

    // Try something

} catch (Exception $e) {

    switch (get_class($e)) {

        case 'AError':
        case 'BError':
            // Handle A or B
            break;

        case 'CError':
            // Handle C
            break;

        case default:
            // Rethrow the Exception
            throw $e;

    }

}
```

Comment: use multiple catches instead of this solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a reasonable alternative if you don't have control over defining the exceptions. Use the name of the exception variable to categorize the exceptions when they are caught. Then check for the exception variable after the try/catch block.

```
$ABError = null;
try {
    // something
} catch (AError $ABError) {  // let the exception fall through
} catch (BError $ABError) {  // let the exception fall through
} catch (Exception $e) {
    handler2($e);
}
if ($ABError) {
    handler1($ABError);
}
```

This somewhat odd looking approach is probably only worth it if there is a lot of duplication between catch block implementations.

Answer (score 5):

As of PHP 8.0 you can use even cleaner way to catch your exceptions when you don't need to output the content of the error (from variable `$e`). However you must replace default `Exception` with `Throwable`.

```
try {
    /* something */
} catch (AError | BError) {
    handler1()
} catch (Throwable) {
    handler2()
}
```

Comment: this can be done in php >= 7.1 versions too.

Comment: No, in previous versions you must write variable name `AError $e`.

Comment: Ohh you skipped capturing the error.
Yeah that's new in 8.0.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Besides fall-through, it's also possible to step over by using **goto**.
It's very useful if you want to see the world burn.

```
<?php

class A_Error extends Exception {}
class B_Error extends Exception {}
class C_Error extends Exception {}

try {
    throw new A_Error();
} 
catch (A_Error $e) { goto abc; }
catch (B_Error $e) { goto abc; }
catch (C_Error $e) {
abc:
    var_dump(get_class($e));
    echo "Gotta Catch 'Em All\n";
}
```

[3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nFQ66)

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, there are many solution written for php version lower than 7.1.

Here is an other simple one for those who doesn't want catch all exception and can't make common interfaces:

```
<?php
$ex = NULL
try {
    /* ... */
} catch (FirstException $ex) {
    // just do nothing here
} catch (SecondException $ex) {
    // just do nothing here
}
if ($ex !== NULL) {
    // handle those exceptions here!
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option not listed here is to use the `code` attribute of an exception, so you can do something like this:

```
try {

    if (1 === $foo) {

         throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid foo: %s', serialize($foo)), 1);
    }

    if (2 === $bar) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid bar: %s', serialize($foo)), 2);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {

    switch ($e->getCode()) {

        case 1:
            // Special handling for case 1
            break;

        case 2:
            // Special handling for case 2
            break;

        default:

            // Special handling for all other cases
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe the OOP purists are angry that you didn't create new exception classes using `extends \Exception` ?

Comment: Got it. That's the whole point of my solution, you don't need to create arbitrary classes just to establish a namespace to throw a specific exception. Im certain it's why they added the ability to specify a code.

Comment: I didn't downvote either but I guess downvoters believe that this does not answer the question. I'd suggest starting the answer with something that makes it clear to the reader that *you* have understood the question and you still want to suggest a total different way for the code flow. This answer really does not answer "how to catch multiple exception *types*" but rather "how to handle multiple different causes for an exception".

Answer (score 1):

A great way is to use `set_exception_handler`.

Warning!!! with PHP 7, you might get a white screen of death for fatal errors.  For example, if you call a method on a non-object you would normally get `Fatal error: Call to a member function your_method() on null` and you would expect to see this if error reporting is on.

The above error will NOT be caught with  `catch(Exception $e)`.
The above error will NOT trigger any custom error handler set by `set_error_handler`.

You must use `catch(Error $e){ }` to catch errors in PHP7. .
This could help:

```
class ErrorHandler{
    public static function excep_handler($e)
    {
        print_r($e);
    }
}
set_exception_handler(array('ErrorHandler','excep_handler'));
```

Comment: ... or you could just write `catch (Throwable $e) { ... }` and be done with it. See also: http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php