# Why isn't my Exception being caught by catch?

Tags: php, exception

I have some code that looks like this

```
# Try to import file
try
{
    DataManager::fileImport($_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name'], 
                            $_POST['zones'], $_POST['statuses']);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    print 'Herp.';
    $response->body = Helpers::getVarDump($e);
}
```

`DataManager::fileImport` is literally a one-line function that throws a normal Exception:

```
static function fileImport($filepath, $zones, $statuses)
{
    throw new Exception('SOME EXCEPTION');
}
```

And yet I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SOME EXCEPTION'...

From the try block. Also 'Herp.' is never printed. Why doesn't the Exception trigger the catch block?

---

EDIT: I should mention I'm using [Tonic](https://github.com/peej/tonic) and PHP 5.3.9

EDIT AGAIN: Here's DataManager (with names replaced with ... for anonymity) http://pastebin.com/daHWBJDC

Comment: It should work. Are you perhaps not showing actual code, and throwing some `RandomLyNamedException` which does not extend `Exception`?

Comment: This looks correct.  Are you sure that this is the only place where you are calling this fileImport method?  If there are others, I would make sure they are also being caught.

Comment: If using 5.3+, did you check your namespaces?

Comment: I just made the class and that's the only place the function is being called. I also checked the line number in the stack trace

Comment: This is the DataManager class http://pastebin.com/daHWBJDC (With some names replaced with ... for anonymity)

Comment: maybe new Exception is an exception in one of the namespaces? have you tried something like catch(Namespace::Exception $e)?

Comment: aaah, good catch @helk. In datamanager.php I was `use`ing Exception, but I wasn't in my main file. Fixed! Perhaps you should edit your answer :-) To summarize, the fix was to `use \Exception` in my main file

Comment: You figured it out yourself m8. I just put you in the right direction ;)

Comment: It took me hours of wondering and investigating why my `\Exception` wasn't being caught, and I finally realized it was because a TypeError is not an Exception: http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325523/470749 Now I'm using `catch (\Exception|\TypeError $e)`

Comment: Netbeans 8.2 only supports up to PHP 7.0, so see Netbeans 9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337305/integrating-new-version-of-php-in-netbeans#comment94361425_49363402

Answer (score 49, accepted):

#### Solution

I neglected to specify `use Exception;` in the file containing the try/catch.

#### Pondering

I know it's intentional that each namespace in PHP should define its own Exception for many reasons, but I still find it odd that `catch(Exception e)` didn't cause any errors when `Exception` in that context wasn't defined. If I were to write `new Exception()` I would get an error.

Oh well, at least I learned something.

Comment: That is odd. Thanks for figuring this out. I come from a Java background and was completely lost as to why the try catch block wasn't interception an Exception.

Comment: Lol ... I just realized I'd left an exception handler in my data class. This explains that :p

Comment: Phew! Thanks for answering your own question. Not finding that out would have been a pain.

Comment: Just `use Exception;` will work. Imports by default import from the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Strange. If i run this code i get the "Herp."

```
<?php

class DataManagerTest {
    static function fileImport($filepath, $zones, $statuses)
    {
        throw new Exception('SOME EXCEPTION');
    }
}

# Try to import file
try
{
    DataManagerTest::fileImport("param1","param2","param3");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    print 'Herp.';
}


?>
```

Comment: That's pretty much identical to what I'm running. The only notable differences is that my class is in a separate file and namespace

Answer (score 2):

You might have an issue with your DataManager class because i copied your code, adapted it to run and i get the exception handled... You problem is elsewhere...

```
class DataManager {
    static function fileImport($filepath, $zones, $statuses){
        throw new Exception('SOME EXCEPTION');
    }
}

try{
    DataManager::fileImport('', '', '');
}catch(Exception $e){
    print 'Herp.';
}
```

Results in

```
Herp.
```

Answer (score 0):

4 years later...

@Hubro, thank you for saving me with that namespace fix!

It does seem counterintuitive at first that it's necessary when throwing a root-level Exception, even though it ultimately makes sense in the general context of namespaces.

For anyone who doesn't want to utilize @Hubro's file-level fix:

`use \Exception;`

You could instead add the backslash in front of Exception in the higher level catch block:

`} catch (\Exception $e) {`

We could all benefit from someone smarter than me providing suggestions on best practices around defining a custom Exception for each namespace.  Any takers?