# How to catch an exception from another class method PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, exception

I'm having trouble catching an exception in PHP

Here's my code.

```
try {
require $this->get_file_name($action);
}

catch (Exception $e) {
//do something//
}
```

and the method being called

```
private function get_file_name($action) {

    $file = '../private/actions/actions_'.$this->group.'.php';

    if (file_exists($file) === false) {
    throw new Exception('The file for this '.$action.' was not found.');
    }

    else {
    return $file;
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message $action was not found.'
Exception: The file for this $action was not found.
```

However If I put a try-catch block inside of the function and call the function, I'm able to catch the exception no problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put your try/catch block in the calling code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369488/try-catch-cannot-work-with-require-once-in-php

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://3v4l.org/afJjt) Are you sure the provided code sample is the one which is called? *(Maybe subclass)* The exception message you're getting does not seem to match with what should be thrown. *(Unevaluated `$action`)*

Answer (score 10):

If you are catching the Exception inside a namespace, make sure that you fall back to the global namespace:

```
...
}(catch \Exception $e) {
  ...
}...
```

You can also have a look at the following resources:

- [Why isn't my Exception being caught by catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097345/why-isnt-my-exception-being-caught-by-catch)
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php, top note by user *zmunoz*

Answer (score 1):

I can't see all of the class body but If You want to use method out of the class it should be Public not Private.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check if file You trying to get exists:

```
var_dump($file = '../private/actions/actions_'.$this->group.'.php');
```

IMO there is no file in this path