# Integrating new version of PHP in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, debian, php-7.1

A month ago PHP 7.1 was released. I've just installed it in my system, running '#php -version' returns me 'PHP 7.1.0' so everything is working fine. But at the time to create a new project in NetBeans, it only allows me '7.0' and the lower 5.X versions
I've been looking for an option to update the new version of PHP in NetBeans but I didnt get a thing.

Other details:
Debian 8 stable system.
PHP7.0 and previous 5.X versions had been installed through 'apt-get', but PHP7.1 through './configure && make && make install'. NetBeans was installed via sh script (not 'apt-get').

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

NetBeans needs to provide PHP 7.1 support by itself, it cannot leverage installed PHP versions. And unfortunately latest NetBeans 8.2 does not support PHP 7.1.

If you want to see it happen, please vote and consider contributing on https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=268317

Comment: Is it still unavailable as of now ?

Comment: Per the thread referenced by @PowerKiKi, 7.2 support is only available in the [latest nightly builds](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/). At this moment, from the [roadmap](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/roadmap.html) it looks like there won't be a production v8.2 that has these updates. We probably need to wait for a v9 which needs to come from Apache now. The roadmap doesn't even have an ETA for NBv9. This is all very "in the air" at this time. Subscribe to the [email lists](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Mailing+lists) for updates.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of the PHP plugin was not in Apache Netbeans 9.0 plugin update center list. However, it was in Apache Netbeans 9.0-rc1's list. I'm not sure why it was left out. To get it in 9.0, you need to add the appropriate plugin repository to your Netbeans plugin update center list. This is done by going to Tools-Plugins and clicking the settings tab and adding the following update centers to the list.

NOTE: I'm not sure which one had it - maybe someone else knows for sure or can explain how the different centers are now organized. Whatever the case, many of the latest versions Netbeans plugins (not just php) can be found in one or some these repositories. Again, I personally don't know which one or ones are now updated. I just added them all...

Name: Additional Development Plugins
URL: http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/dev/uc/final/main/catalog.xml.gz

Name: DukeScript Update Center
URL: http://dukescript.com/downloads/netbeans/8.2/updates.xml

Name: Latest Development Build
URL: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

Name: Netbeans Distribution
URL: https://netbeans.apache.org/nb/updates/9.0/updates.xml.gz

Name: Netbeans IDE 8.2 Update Center
URL: https://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz

Name: Plugin Portal
URL:  http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/9.0/catalog.xml.gz

Name: Plugin Portal 8.2
URL:  http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/8.2/catalog.xml.gz

Comment: Thank you for this. This helped me to get my PHP stuff going with Netbeans9. Does anyone know if there will be some preconfigured packages again in the future for Windows/Linux/Mac like there used to be for Netbeans 8.x?

Comment: thats the blog post stroy to get extras in general for NB: https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-happened-to-my

Answer (score 2):

PHP 7.1 is now available under the NetBeans 9.0 Beta, I managed to import all my plugins from 8.2 without a problem but beware it is a development version and it sometimes is a tad slow, but at least it has support for nullable return types etc.

[NetBeans 9.0 Beta Download](http://apache.cbox.biz/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0-beta/)

Answer (score 0):

Build 880 i just installed and seems to work in general but probably not at all :)

Its netbeans 10 incl. php7.2 and php7.3 support (BETA! all in one packages)

https://builds.apache.org/job/incubator-netbeans-linux/

Answer (score 0):

I succesfully followed https://github.com/czjvic/php-7.1-for-netbeans-8.2 using the Netbeans 10 PHP modules.

You can find the latest Netbeans 10 build here:

https://builds.apache.org/job/incubator-netbeans-linux/lastCompletedBuild/artifact/nbbuild/

Download the file named like `NetBeans-dev-incubator-netbeans-linux-881-on-20181022-release.zip`.

From my backup, I also needed to copy the file `org-netbeans-modules-php-dbgp.jar`.