# Having issue with extended exceptions using Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, exception, try-catch, yii2

I'm using the `Yii 2` framework and it uses a number of extended exceptions and I'm having an issue with them where I threw a `UserException` but it ended up being caught by the base `Exception` but I'm not sure why!?

The code:

```
try {

    //........

    if ($reader->count() > 0) {     

        if (!$already_active) {         
            //.....
        } else {
            throw new UserException('You have already activated your account; you may continue to login.');             
        }

    }

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    // User exception above is caught in here?

} catch (UserException $e) {

    // Rethrow the exception
    throw $e;

}
```

Shouldn't the `User Exception` be passed onto and caught by the second `catch`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block.

The catch block for `Exception` will be executed since `Exception` is a parent of `UserException` and therefore any object of type `UserException` is also of type `Exception`.

Therefore you should refactor your code to have the catch block for child classes first. In your case `UserException` should be first.

Comment: + 1, You're answer looks great buddy, But I think that there will be no difference if we put `UserException` in first. No?

Comment: Oh ok, I thought it would be caught by the "matching" exception type; didn't know `Exception` was a catch-all; thought that's why the `finally` was added in PHP 5.5 for.

Comment: I disagree. The exception handler uses `instanceof` to match the exception thrown and executes the code in the first `catch` which matches. In this case `UserException` matches both catch blocks so it is just a matter of which comes first. For more information look at http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/19/8/7

Comment: umm, you're totally right, but, I just tested it right now, there was no difference :D

Comment: @AliMasudianPour check the example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14360210/428543). I have tested it and the results are correct.

Comment: @topher I am so sorry :) I wasn't using the correct namespace. You're right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at `UserException` class you can see:

```
class UserException extends Exception
```

Therefore, `Exception` has the higher priority.

However you can do just:

```
//if something's wrong
throw new \yii\base\UserException('You have already activated your account; you may continue to login.');
```

Comment: I use this at the top `use yii\base\UserException;` so I can just reference it as `UserException` :)

Comment: @Brett :)) Thanks buddy, there is no difference at all.