# PHP log error messages to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to set up an error reporting system for my site. Currently, I am adding try/catch blocks to most of my code. For my catch blocks I have a log.php file which is included.

My catch block looks like this,

```
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    require_once 'includes/log.php';
}
```

The included log.php file contains the following code,

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=centers", $dbusername, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO cent_log (ip, message, time, username) VALUES (:val1, :val2, :val3, :val4)");
$stmt->bindParam(':val1', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$stmt->bindParam(':val2', $e);
$stmt->bindParam(':val3', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
$stmt->bindParam(':val4', $_SESSION['user_IP']);
$stmt->execute();
```

However, when my catch block is triggered the error message from $e is not getting passed along. When I check my recent database entries I see that when PDO tries to pass in the $e, its value is 'null'

Does anyone have any ideas? Basically I just want to log all errors to my database for review. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your *actual* error logs?

Comment: What is the difference between `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and `$_SESSION['user_IP']`?

Comment: $_SESSION['user_ip'] is just a variable I made to store the initial IP when a user logs in.

Comment: I can't believe someone would try to log a database error into... a database.

Answer (score -2):

Try catching the generic Exception instead of PDOException.

Refer to this answer:
[Catching multiple exception types in one catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439581/catching-multiple-exception-types-in-one-catch-block)

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I felt the explanation of why was in the cited previous answer. I should have used a comment instead of an 'answer'. Noted.