# PHP unable to caught exception thrown inside catch

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I have extended `Exception` class two times to caught different types of exceptions. When first exception is caught I check for another error and if there is an error I throw a new exception again.
The problem is that  I can not caught the second exception.

```
class FIRST extends Exception {}
class SECOND extends Exception {}

try {
    throw new FIRST("FIRST", 1);
} catch(FIRST $e) {
    //caught

    if(sth) {
        echo 'ok'; //printed
        throw new SECOND("SECOND", 1);
        echo 'ok'; //never printed
    }
}

catch(SECOND $e) {
    //not caught
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    //caught
}

finally {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `catch` blocks only catch exceptions coming from the `try` block.

If you need to catch exceptions thrown from any of the `catch` blocks you have to wrap the inner code in another `try-catch` structure:

```
try {
    throw new FIRST("FIRST", 1);
} catch(FIRST $e) {
    //caught

    try {
        if(sth) {
            echo 'ok'; //printed
            throw new SECOND("SECOND", 1);
            echo 'ok'; //never printed
        }
    } catch (SECOND $e) {
        //caught
    }
}

catch(SECOND $e) {
    //not caught
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    //caught
}

finally {
    //
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? I do not want to nest them inside each other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439581/catching-multiple-exception-types-in-one-catch-block I want to do smth like the first answer.

Comment: If you throw additional exceptions from within a catch block it will not be caught by the other ones. That's just how `try-catch` works. The answer you linked to doesn't make that work.