# Catch different Exception types

Tags: php, symfony, exception, try-catch

I have a very simple function to check whether an Entity exists in a bundle:

```
public function checkExists($bundle, $val)
{
    try{
       $this->em->getRepository($bundle.':'.$val);
    }catch (MappingException $e){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So I have the following cases:

```
Input                        |    Expected    |    Actual
'AppBundle', 'Company'       |    true        |    true
'AppBundle', 'NONEXISTANT'   |    false       |    false (MappingException caught)
'NONEXISTANT', 'Company'     |    false       |    500 (ORMException not caught)
'NONEXISTANT', 'NONEXISTANT' |    false       |    500 (ORMException not caught)
```

So I see that the problem is that there are different exceptions thrown, but how could I return false for either of the cases of one part non-existant? Is there a "general" way to catch exceptions in symfony as `catch (Exception $e)` with `use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;` does not catch it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching multiple exception types in one catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439581/catching-multiple-exception-types-in-one-catch-block)

Comment: You really don't want to rely on exceptions for this sort of stuff.  Take a look at Doctrine's metadata.  In particular: $em->getClassMetadata($entityClassName);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of things to do: 
You can catch all exceptions firstly, then you can handle each one differently:

```
public function checkExists($bundle, $val)
{
    try{
       $this->em->getRepository($bundle.':'.$val);
    } catch (\Exception $e){ // \Exception  is the global scope exception
        if ($e instanceof MappingException || $e instanceof ORMException) {
            return false;
        } 
        throw $e; //Rethrow it if you can't handle it here.
    }

    return true;
}
```

Alternatevely have multiple catches:

```
 public function checkExists($bundle, $val)
{
    try{
       $this->em->getRepository($bundle.':'.$val);
    } catch (MappingException $e){
       return false;
    } catch (ORMException $e) {
       return false;
    }  //Other exceptions are still unhandled.

    return true;
}
```

If you're using PHP 7.1 + then you can also do:

```
public function checkExists($bundle, $val)
{
    try{
       $this->em->getRepository($bundle.':'.$val);
    } catch (MappingException | ORMException $e){ //Catch either MappingException or ORMException 
       return false;
    }  //Other exceptions are still unhandled.

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Exception Listener and handle them there.

```
class ExceptionListener
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $e = $event->getException();
        if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
            $this->logger->notice('Validation error' , $e->getViolations());
        } elseif ($e instanceof DomainException) {
            $this->logger->warning('Exception ' . get_class($e) , ['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
            $event->setResponse(
            new JsonResponse(['error' => $this->translator->trans($e->getOutMessage())], 400)
            );
        } else {
            $event->setResponse(
                new JsonResponse(['error' => $this->translator->trans('http.internal_server_error')], 500)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Update services.yml

```
  app.exception_listener:
    class: Application\Listeners\ExceptionListener
    arguments: ['@domain.logger']
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Further reading about listeners and events https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

I am not sure that you should create situations that throw Mapping exceptions, when your application is shipped.