# How to disable fatal error in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When my app couldn't connect to the database it throws a Fatal Error message :

[image]

[image]

so how to show a custom error page for this error like 404 page error ?

is there any configuration to do in symfony config.yml ?

thank you !

Comment: [How to Customize Error Pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html). Also: In the `prod` environment exceptions should generate an error page (instead of spitting out details / stack traces) by default.

Comment: the response code is 200

Comment: You mean you get a response code of 200 (which is OK) and it can't connect to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display custom 404, 403, 500 errors if you will override your default Twig-based template. For this purpose you should create folder "TwigBundle" in your app/Resources directory and emulate the following structure:[image: Folder structure] 
That should help. The mechanism is the same as for 404 page. This also can help you to extend my answer: [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create Service and mark it as exception listener. In this service you can log your exception and display any response you like. You can actually do anything that can be done within Symfony Service.

More details:

[Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)

[My previous answer on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372714/6335604)