# Handling Multiple Exception Types For One Try Block

Tags: php, exception

Is there a cleaner way to handle multiple exception types for a single try block? As you will see below we have specific code that is to be executed for the different catch statements.

This function is one of many which use the repeated try catch logic. Is it possible to eliminate this repeated catch code somehow?

```
public function add_payment_method(Request $request){

    try{

        // Try to do some stuff

    } catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {

        /*
            CODE FOR THIS SPECIFIC EXCEPTION
        */

    } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {


         /*
            CODE FOR THIS SPECIFIC EXCEPTION
        */


    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {


         /*
            CODE FOR THIS SPECIFIC EXCEPTION
        */


    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {


         /*
            CODE FOR THIS SPECIFIC EXCEPTION
        */


    } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {


         /*
            CODE FOR THIS SPECIFIC EXCEPTION
        */


    } catch (\Exception $e) {


         /*
            CODE FOR GENERIC EXCEPTION
        */


    }

}
```

Comment: Catch `Stripe\Error\Base` instead of the specific ones

Answer (score 0):

All of these errors extend `Stripe\Error\Base`, so catching `Stripe\Error\Base` should cover the more specific ones.

That said, Stripe provides different exception types because you **should** be doing different actions in response to the different types. A `RateLimit` exception is something you should queue and retry later. A `Card` exception is something you should kick back to the user to fix. An `Authentication` error might mean your entire app is unable to take credit cards because your API token is missing/wrong and you're losing $$$.

Answer (score -2):

See [Catching multiple exception types in one catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439581/catching-multiple-exception-types-in-one-catch-block)

Apart from a thousand ifelse, one can do

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    switch ($e) {
        case $e instanceof Exception1:
            ...;
            break;
        case $e instanceof Exception2:
            ...;
            break;
        default:
            ...;
    }
}
```