# php execute variable undefined in try block that sets prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I apologize if this has been asked before. I can not ask the question properly then.

I am getting an error on the "bindParam" that states `$tools is undefined`. I am unsure since I am still new too PHP. I am confused how or why it is out of scope. I am not sure because it is an object or what.

```
function query_group_by_param($param) {
try {
    include('connection.php');
    if(isset($db))
        $tools = $db->prepare("SELECT t.t_id as id, t.item_code as code, t.item_name as name,
                                t.retail_price as retail, t.sale_price as price,
                                t.item_pieces as  pieces, t.qty as quantity,
                                t.sold as sold, t.description as description,
                                b.brand as brand, c.category as category,
                                tt.tool_type as sections,
                                i.image as image
                               FROM Tools as t
                               INNER JOIN Brands as b on t.b_id = b.b_id
                               INNER JOIN Categories as c ON t.c_id = c.c_id
                               INNER JOIN Images AS i ON t.t_id = i.t_id
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN Types AS tt ON t.tt_id = tt.tt_id
                               WHERE tt.tool_type = :tool");
    $tools->bindParam(':tool', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR, 15); 
    $tools->execute();

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'unable to retrieve data';
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
$tool = $tools->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$tools->closeCursor();
return $tool; 
}
```

Also, Without the `if(isset($db)` under the `include(connection.php')` that 
shows up as if it is undefined.

Any suggestions or links would be greatly appreciated. please.

Comment: I would encourage you to re-think the if statement - if(isset($db)). If $db is not set, then the next line, $tools = $db->prepare... will not execute. I think a better way of checking for that, would be to check if it is not set, then to throw an exception. You can catch more than 1 exception type as outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439581/catching-multiple-exception-types-in-one-catch-block
To help any further, please post your connection.php (remove all sensitive data such as passwords) and post the PHP error that you are receiving.

Comment: here is a link to the connection.php 
[connection.php](https://gist.github.com/mikeyhavoc/2d223452233bafdb5311bd033feaf9f5)
and also the function that im still trying to work on but with a comment or two so you can see it. 
[function.php](https://gist.github.com/mikeyhavoc/f85fbae3eaad9d54c439f7f26b97e2d7)

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_tools\private\functions.php:73 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php_tools\details.php(23): single_item_images_query('16') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_tools\private\functions.php on line 73

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake to use a `if` statement. The `if` statement without curly braces `{}` then statement only after the "if" condition get affected.

```
if(isset($db)) {
  $tools = $db->prepare("SELECT t.t_id as id, t.item_code as code, t.item_name as name,
                            t.retail_price as retail, t.sale_price as price,
                            t.item_pieces as  pieces, t.qty as quantity,
                            t.sold as sold, t.description as description,
                            b.brand as brand, c.category as category,
                            tt.tool_type as sections,
                            i.image as image
                           FROM Tools as t
                           INNER JOIN Brands as b on t.b_id = b.b_id
                           INNER JOIN Categories as c ON t.c_id = c.c_id
                           INNER JOIN Images AS i ON t.t_id = i.t_id
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN Types AS tt ON t.tt_id = tt.tt_id
                           WHERE tt.tool_type = :tool");
  $tools->bindParam(':tool', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR, 15); 
  $tools->execute();
}
```

Comment: Well pointed out. I automatically made the presumption the poster was aware of this. FYI for the poster, the reason this matters, is because if $db is not set, then PHP will not execute $db->prepare, but will continue onto the next line after ; which is $tools->bindParam and requires $tools to be defined. At this point, it has not been defined and results in the error described.

Comment: if I set up the `if (!isset($db))` 
then `$db->prepare` is undefined.. so I dont quite understand :/

Comment: it explains, if `$db` hasn't set and it might be `undefined`. check your `connection.php` script and see how to define the `$db`

Comment: if it helps heres a link to the scripts  
[connection.php](https://gist.github.com/mikeyhavoc/2d223452233bafdb5311bd033feaf9f5)
<br>
then the function  [function.php](https://gist.github.com/mikeyhavoc/f85fbae3eaad9d54c439f7f26b97e2d7)

Comment: I will check the connection next.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_tools\private\functions.php:73 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php_tools\details.php(23): single_item_images_query('16') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_tools\private\functions.php on line 73